# How to set an environment variable with a '$' in the value in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I enter a value that has a dollar sign `$` the environment only reads the first part of it, and that's because the env file generated puts double quotes in the values instead of single quotes. Any way around that? The value can't be changed because it's an access token from a service I don't control.

Example:

The env file generated is like:
`export MY_VAR="my$value"`

Running that results in:
`MY_VAR=my`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64519029, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42901684, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51545529

Answer (score 4):

Either escape the dollar signs with three backslashes (works using either the web console or the command line):

```sh
eb setenv -e my-environment MY_VARIABLE=\\\$foobar
```

Or with a strong quotes (`''`) you would only have to use one backslash to escape:

```sh
eb setenv -e my-environment MY_VARIABLE='\$foobar'
```

Answer (score 3):

It is evaluating `$value` as a variable and converting it to an empty string since that variable doesn't exist in the environment. Try escaping the `$` character like this:

`export MY_VAR="my\$value"`

Alternatively, use single quotes which should prevent variable expansion:

`export MY_VAR='my$value'`

Comment: I tried escaping but that ends up as ```my\\``` in the environment, and I can't control the quotes for the values, that's handled by Beanstalk. I ended up using a different character and replacing it in the code. Weak solution but works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the dollar sign and its subsequent characters are interpreted (e.g. by bash) as an environment variable and substituted by its value. While environment variable $value is (obviously) empty it is simply evaluated to "my" and (empty string).

It took me quite a while to find a workaround, but this one (although pretty ugly) works for me: Simply surround your string with

```
$(echo '<your string here>')
```

and make sure that all dollar signs are escaped with '\' sign, e.g. use the following string as ElasticBeanStalk's environment property value

```
MY_VAR=$(echo 'my\$value')
```

As a result, the value 'my$value' will be passed to your application as MY_VAR.