# Any way to escape "illegal characters" in elastic beanstalk environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create a new elastic beanstalk environment for a Rails app, and I'm passing in details of an existing RDS instance as environment variables.  This RDS instance was created from a snapshot of a previous elastic beanstalk instance - however this one was "controlled" by elastic beanstalk instead of being passed in as environment variables.

For the RDS_PASSWORD value I'm passing in the existing password for the instance (which contains a ^ and *), but when attempting to launch the environment I get the following error -

> Could not launch environment: Tag value < password here >
>   contains illegal characters.Any letter in any language, any numeric
>   character, whitespace, invisible seperator and _ . : / = + - @ are
>   allowed.

I attempted to escape the "illegal characters" with backslash, but still get the error.

Comment: Where is that error coming from? Are you having trouble setting the `RDS_PASSWORD` value (via `eb setenv` or the EB console), is Rails failing to start, or is it something else? Also, have you considered changing the db password to something that does not contain ^ or *?

Comment: @Brian - I was attempting to create the new environment via the AWS EB console (website).  After filling in all the configuration wizard options the error was thrown when attempting to start the new environment.  Ultimately I did just change the password remove the "illegal characters" to get around the error. I was asking the question in case there was a known workaround for this if this issue ever crops up in the future and changing the value is "out of my control" in some way.

Comment: Interesting. I was able to set an environment variable to a string containing both `^` and `*` using `eb setenv`, so another option might have been to defer setting the password until after the environment is created.