# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk Environment properties with a $

Tags: java, amazon-s3, tomcat8

I am attempting to set a property that contains $ in it as a Environmental Property (Configure -> Software -> Environment properties) that will eventually get passed to my tomcat context.xml file (all running on AMI - Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.0.1). It seems like it won't accept $ characters (source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html). It appears that they are being interpreted as bash variables.  Can I escape the $ some how, I've tried \$ and (double backslash)\$ with no luck.  Am I missing something or am I just out of luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a bit or trial and error it looks like you need 3 backslashes to escape the $ character.  `\\\$myData`