# Dollar sign in password breaking mysqldump on AWS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am hosting a Laravel app on Elastic Beanstalk. I have an artisan command that runs `mysqldump`:

```php
$command = 'mysqldump -h%s -u%s -p%s %s > ' . storage_path($filename);
$c = sprintf(
            $command,
            config('database.connections.host'),
            config('database.connections.username'),
            config('database.connections.password'),
            $destinationDatabase
        );
$this->process = new Process($c);
```

This works when the password (which I store in an environment variable) does not have a dollar sign in it. But when the password does have a dollar sign in it, it is cut off and the command then fails. E.g. if the password is "test$me", I get this error:

> The command "mysqldump -hhostname.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com -urandomname -ptest db_name > db.sql" failed

I.e. instead of inserting "test$me" for the password, it inserts "test".

I have tried adding single quotes around the password in the environment variable, the same thing happens:

> The command "mysqldump -hhostname.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com -urandomname -p'test' db_name > db.sql" failed

Comment: Does adding an escaping backslash before the $ makes a difference? Like this 'test\$me'?

Comment: Can you show your config file?

Comment: You might have better luck creating a my.cnf file that only the php file can load, and use that instead.

Comment: But according to https://superuser.com/questions/123928/escaping-a-password-using-mysqldump-console, you should be able to use single quotes in the command line, as long as the config file also has the password in single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43872864) and prefixed three backslashes to `$` in my Elastic Beanstalk environment variable:

`test\\\$me`

Answer (score 0):

> dollar sign in it. But when the password does have a dollar sign in it, it is cut off and the command then fails. E.g. if the password is "test$me"

It looks like the invocation is using the string non-escaped and that is then resolved by the shell (which also uses `$` to denote variables). You must escape all arguments passed with [escapeshellarg()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to counter that:

```
$c = sprintf(
            $command,
            escapeshellarg(config('database.connections.host')),
            escapeshellarg(config('database.connections.username')),
            escapeshellarg(config('database.connections.password')),
            escapeshellarg($destinationDatabase)
        );
```

Comment: @AlaaMorad: no, that would produce different output.

Comment: It produces this output: The command "mysqldump -hhostname.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com -urandomname -p'test' db_name > db.sql" failed

Comment: This indicates the problem is also with your config file. Where you put your password? Dotenv? or config.php?

Comment: In the Elastic Beanstalk environment variable

Comment: what exactly does it mean? Can you edit your question and show the config where you set the password (remember to use fake data)

Comment: my point is that if that's shell script (or evaluated by shell somehow) then you got `$xxx` part already expanded by shell (by default unknown variable is expanded to empty string silently). In PHP that'd be also possible however you most likely end  up seeing PHP notice

Comment: The problem is to do with Elastic Beanstalk.