# Where are my environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk for AL2?

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I'm using `elastic beanstalk` to deploy a `Django` app. I'd like to `SSH` on the `EC2` instance to execute some shell commands but the environment variables don't seem to be there. I specified them via the AWS GUI (configuration -> environment properties) and they seem to work during the boot-up of my app.

I tried activating and deactivating the virtual env via:

```
source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
```

Is there some environment (or script I can run) to access an environment with all the properties set? Otherwise, I'm hardly able to run any command like `python3 manage.py ...` since there is no settings module configured (I know how to specify it manually but my app needs around 7 variables to work).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try running the command `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment` after you ssh into the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 17):

*During* deployment, the environment properties are readily available to your `.platform` hook scripts.

*After* deployment, e.g. when using `eb ssh`, you need to load the environment properties manually.

One option is to use the EB [get-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html) tool. The environment properties can be accessed either individually (using the `-k` option), or as a JSON or YAML object with key-value pairs.

For example, one way to `export` all environment properties would be:

```sh
export $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config --output YAML environment | 
         sed -r 's/: /=/' | xargs)
```

Here the `get-config` part returns all environment properties as YAML, the `sed` part replaces the `': '` in the YAML output with `'='`, and the `xargs` part fixes quoted numbers.

Note this does **not** require `sudo`.

Alternatively, you could refer to [this AWS knowledge center post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210917225033/https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-linux2/):

> Important: On Amazon Linux 2, all environment properties are centralized into a single file called `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`. You must use this file during Elastic Beanstalk's application deployment process *only*. ...

The post describes how to make a copy of the `env` file during deployment, using `.platform` hooks, and how to set permissions so you can access the file later.

You can also perform similar steps manually, using SSH. Once you have the copy set up, with the proper permissions, you can `source` it.

Beware:

> Note: Environment properties with spaces or special characters are interpreted by the Bash shell and can result in a different value.

Comment: Also see these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888738, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62212223

Comment: What is the solution for env vars with special characters? Does wrapping them in quotes work?

Comment: @Daniel: Not sure. A quick search turned up some related discussions that mention e.g. [using \\\ or quotes to escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37619164), or [using base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64519029), but I haven't tried any of those yet.

Comment: [This AWS post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell) mentions yet another approach: saving the environment variables to `/etc/profile.d/local.sh` during deployment. This uses [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to handle JSON output from `get-config`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the environment variables in eb script elastic beanstalk
Use this

```
$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k ENVURL)
{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }
    $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k ENVURL)
```